# Discord.js recordings bot not configured for one voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hey guys i'm trying to create discord voice recorder bot for professional community channel. I'm new at this things. This bot feature is only configured for one channel but right now bot not summon on channel. When i send command (!record) i dont get any error on terminal i don't understand where i do wrong

Any idea for this stuff ?

```
/* Required Modules */
const { entersState, joinVoiceChannel, VoiceConnectionStatus, EndBehaviorType } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { createWriteStream } = require('node:fs');
const prism = require('prism-media');
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream');
const { Client, Intents, MessageAttachment, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);
const fs = require('fs');
const allowedChannelId = '1191088050332237954';
const messageChannelId = '1191088050332237954';

/* Initialize Discord Client */
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates
    ]
});

/* Collection to store voice state */
client.voiceManager = new Collection();

/* Ready event */
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Connected as", client.user.tag, "to discord!");
});

/* When message is sent*/
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    /* If content starts with `!record` */
    if (messageChannelId !== allowedChannelId) {
        return;
    }

    if (message.content.startsWith('!record')) {
        /* If member do not have admin perms */
        if (!message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use this command.');

        /* Get the voice channel the user is in */
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel

        /* Check if the bot is in voice channel */
        let connection = client.voiceManager.get(message.channel.guild.id)

        /* If the bot is not in voice channel */
        if (!connection) {
            /* if user is not in any voice channel then return the error message */
            if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use this command!")

            /* Join voice channel*/
            connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: voiceChannel.id,
                guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
                selfDeaf: false,
                selfMute: true,
                adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });

            /* Add voice state to collection */
            client.voiceManager.set(message.channel.guild.id, connection);

            await entersState(connection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, 20e3);

            const receiver = connection.receiver;

            /* When user speaks in vc*/
            receiver.speaking.on('start', (userId) => {
                if (userId !== message.author.id) return;

                /* create live stream to save audio */
                createListeningStream(receiver, userId, client.users.cache.get(userId));
            });

            /* Return success message */
            return message.channel.send(`️ I am now recording ${voiceChannel.name}`);
        } else if (connection) {
            /* Send waiting message */
            const msg = await message.channel.send("Please wait while I am preparing your recording...")
            /* wait for 5 seconds */
            await sleep(5000)

            /* disconnect the bot from voice channel */
            connection.destroy();

            /* Remove voice state from collection */
            client.voiceManager.delete(message.channel.guild.id)

            const filename = `./recordings/${message.author.id}`;

            /* Create ffmpeg command to convert pcm to mp3 */
            const process = new ffmpeg(`${filename}.pcm`);
            process.then(function (audio) {
                audio.fnExtractSoundToMP3(`${filename}.mp3`, async function (error, file) {
                    //edit message with recording as attachment
                    await msg.edit({
                        content: ` Here is your recording!`,
                        files: [new MessageAttachment(`./recordings/${message.author.id}.mp3`, 'recording.mp3')]
                    });

                    //delete both files
                    fs.unlinkSync(`${filename}.pcm`)
                    fs.unlinkSync(`${filename}.mp3`)
                });
            }, function (err) {
                /* handle error by sending error message to discord */
                return msg.edit(`❌ An error occurred while processing your recording: ${err.message}`);
            });
        }
    }
})

client.login("BOT TOKEN")
//------------------------- F U N C T I O N S ----------------------//

/* Function to write audio to file (from discord.js example) */
function createListeningStream(receiver, userId, user) {
    const opusStream = receiver.subscribe(userId, {
        end: {
            behavior: EndBehaviorType.AfterSilence,
            duration: 100,
        },
    });

    const oggStream = new prism.opus.OggLogicalBitstream({
        opusHead: new prism.opus.OpusHead({
            channelCount: 2,
            sampleRate: 48000,
        }),
        pageSizeControl: {
            maxPackets: 10,
        },
    });

    const filename = `./recordings/${user.id}.pcm`;

    const out = createWriteStream(filename, { flags: 'a' });
    console.log(` Started recording ${filename}`);

    pipeline(opusStream, oggStream, out, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.warn(`❌ Error recording file ${filename} - ${err.message}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`✅ Recorded ${filename}`);
        }
    });
}
```

- I added this command to work on a specific channel
  const allowedChannelId = '1191088050332237954';
  const messageChannelId = '1191088050332237954';
- I did upgrade intents to gatewayintentbits
- I added this command
  `if (message.Channel.Id !== allowed.Channel.Id) { return; }`

And now when i try to command bot its not summon on channel and **i don't get any error on terminal**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the bot to respond to a message command using `!` as the prefix. You're however not passing the required `MessageContent` intent in the intent array. The bot client needs this intent. Updated client initialization:

```
/* Initialize Discord Client */
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});
```

Don't forget to also enable this option in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) ([Here](https://umod.org/community/discord/40519-how-to-enable-message-content-intent) is a small tutorial.)

Comment: This intents solved my problem but i have new one. I'm trying to record 5 persons on voice channel but right now bot's just recording one person any idea for this ? 


Edit : when i add **MessageContent** i had to change ` files: [new MessageAttachment(`./recordings/${message.author.id}.mp3`, 'recording.mp3')]` to  files: `[new AttachmentBuildert(`./recordings/${message.author.id}.mp3`, 'recording.mp3')]`